# Android Module reference layout error

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, module

I'm not good at using the modules on Android

So I have a problem. When I called module activity it must refer the module layout but actually it's referring to the App layout.

I guess it might R.java problem, but I'm not sure.

Here is how it is setup in my project.
[image: Example]

Comment: What's your project structure? Is the login module is a library module on which the app module depends?

Comment: app module is main, login module is library

Answer (score 2):

During the build process, any resources in a library module are ignored if the same resource appears in the main module. That's why `androidmodule2.MainActivity` is picking up the `activity_main` layout from the `app` module: the resource of the same name in the `library` module is being thrown away during the build process.

Change the name of the layout resource in one of the modules so there's no name collision and all should then be well. (Well, at least this particular problem should go away.)

Comment: Great explanation. If anyone want to test it, just unpack the apk and check the files inside it.